# Override foreign key column name using an embedded object

Tags: java, jpa

If an Embeddable object has defined a `OneToOne` relationship to an entity. How can the Entity that uses the Embeddable object override the column name for the relationship.

Using the following entities:

```
@Entity
public class User {

    @Id
    private int id;
    @Embedded
    private CubeLocation cubeLocation;
}

@Embeddable
public class CubeLocation { 
    @OneToOne
    private MailBox mailBox;            
    // .. other non-relevant fields
}

@Entity
public class MailBox {  
    @Id
    private String name;
    private String cell;
}
```

The database table for the User entity would have the columns ID and MAILBOX_NAME. How can the name of the database column can be changed from MAILBOX_NAME to MBX_ID?

I have tried to define an `AssociationOverride` annotation to the `User` entity, but I am getting this error in that case:

```
    @Entity
    @AssociationOverride(
            name="cubeLocation.mailBox",
            joinColumns=@JoinColumn(name="MBX_ID"))
    public class User {
    }
```

Error:

> org.hibernate.AnnotationException: Illegal attempt to define a
>   @JoinColumn with a mappedBy association: cubeLocation.mailBox

Answer (score 1):

Association overrides should go on the embeddable:

```
@Entity
public class User {

    @Id
    private int id;

    @Embedded
    @AssociationOverride(
            name="mailBox",
            joinColumns=@JoinColumn(name="MBX_ID"))
    private CubeLocation cubeLocation;
}
```

Comment: I've tried your solution, but I still get the same error: `org.hibernate.AnnotationException: Illegal attempt to define a @JoinColumn with a mappedBy association: cubeLocation.mailBox`

Comment: Well that should work. I would temporarily remove the override  and try simply adding  '@JoinColumn(name = "MBX_ID")` to the `@OneToOne` itself. The outcome of that should indicate if the problem is with the override or with some other mapping.

Comment: If I add the `@JoinColumn` to the `@OneToOne`it works correctly(But this changes the name for all other entities using the Embedded object). If I add the `@JoinColumn` to the `@OneToOne` and the `@AssociationOverride` to the Entity it also works correctly. However, if I add the `@AssociationOverride` to the entity without setting the `@JoinColumn` in the `@OneToOne`, I am getting the `Illegal attempt to define a @JoinColumn with a mappedBy association` error. Why do I need to set the `@JoinColumn` in the Embedded to be able to set the `@AssociationOverride` in the entity?

Comment: The `@JoinColumn` defines the default join column - enabling you to use the embeddable entity without the need to override the association. In your case, you want to override the defualt behavior, so you combine it with `@AssociationOverride`.